# What would cause SP Foundation 2013 to say "Working on it..." once a day?

Tags: 2013

Sharepoint will spin and say "Working on it..." for about 15 seconds once a day in the morning, to whoever tries to access the site first.

Is there a database timeout or something happening?

Answer (score 3):

This is called JIT (Just-in-Time) lag. What is happening is the IIS Application Pool had shutdown overnight due to no activity taking place (no web requests). When the pool starts back up again, it must compile the appropriate binaries, or JIT them, which takes time.

A solution to this would be looking for a 'warmup' script. There are many different ones available if you do a cursory search, e.g. http://sharepointwarmup.codeplex.com/.